# I can't modify the app.config file

Tags: c#, runtime, app-config

What's wrong with the following code:

```
private static void UpdateAppSettings(string settingName, string settingValue)
{
    if (settingName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("settingName");
    if (settingValue == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("settingValue");

    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    var appSettings = config.AppSettings;

    var setting = appSettings.Settings[settingName];
    setting.Value = settingValue;

    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("AppSettings");
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't save the new settings. It first opens the app.config file. After going to appsetting area. It then finds a specific key as `settingName` and changes the value to `settingValue`. Afterwards, it saves the file and refreshes it. It almost works; up to `config.Save(...)`. But after that I don't know what happens.

Comment: Do you get an error? Is the file not updated? More information is needed on exactly *what* your problem is.

Comment: have you tried it in debug or release mode? As far as I can remember this only works proper with release.

Comment: check the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758389/why-are-application-settings-read-only-in-app-config

Comment: No not even in release mode working.

Comment: I didn't get an error. but my app config file didn't change.

Answer (score 1):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216809/configurationmanager-doesnt-save-settings) seems to be the same as what you are asking.

The answer looks to be this:

```
config.AppSettings[settingName] = settingValue;
```

EDIT:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995012/using-appsettings-in-the-dal-layer) has the answer I think

```
config.AppSettings.Settings[settingName]
```